# Why do I get "Error 503" when performing multiple MySQL requests?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this big Excel file which I parse and then try to upload to the database. What I do is that I first try to insert the data, I then check if the data is added to the DB or if I get a "duplicate ID" in my `errorInfo()` and in that case try to update the row in the DB if the values are different from the original ones.

Now, if I dont add a `var_dump()` in my `insertToDB()` function I will get an "Error 503" at the end of the excecution (which I can see in the Console of my Browser).

Is there a reason for that? Is it maybe related to the server timeout? How can I fix this?

**EDIT 1:**

This is essentially my `insertToDB()` function, or more precisely:

```
function insertToDB($data) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO
                `invoice` (
                    id,
                    date,
                    expiration_date,
                    amount_without_vat,
                    amount_vat,
                    balance,
                    record_reference,
                    customer_id,
                    order_number,
                    query_number,
                    created
                ) VALUES (
                    :id,
                    :date,
                    :expiration_date,
                    :amount_without_vat,
                    :amount_vat,
                    :balance,
                    :record_reference,
                    :customer_id,
                    :order_number,
                    :query_number,
                    NOW()
                )";

    $query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

    $values = [
        ':id' => $data["invoice_number"],
        ':date' => $data["invoice_date"],
        ':expiration_date' => $data["invoice_expiration_date"],
        ':amount_without_vat' => $data["amount_without_vat"],
        ':amount_vat' => $data["amount_vat"],
        ':balance' => $data["balance"],
        ':record_reference' => $data["record_reference"],
        ':customer_id' => $data["id"],
        ':order_number' => $data["order_number"],
        ':query_number' => $data["query_number"]
    ];

    $query->execute($values);
}
```

This is excecuted around 700 times. If I don't add a `var_dump()` at the end, I will see an "Error 503" in the console of my Browser.

Comment: Impossible to know without the offending piece of code..

Comment: @Oscar added the function, even if I don't see anything wring with it. And it is weird of by adding the `var_dump()` I don't get the error.